# reading and printing matrix from stdin

Tags: arrays, c, matrix, dynamic-memory-allocation

Well I posted this before but it's kinda improved now, and I only have one problem (I guess).

The assignment was to write a function which reads an integer matrix given in a ‘.txt file’ using
I/O redirection, then write another function to print it.

I read txt into a 1D array (arr) then create 2D matrix (mat) out of it, before those, I allocated memory dynamically bc our professor asked to do it that way. The problem is that arr seems to be changing when I put it on for loop and try to address it for the matrix. I would appreciate any ideas... Also, it would be helpful if you guys can comment on my way of allocating memory. (Don't forget we have 3 different input.txts some of them has -5.58234 like values or they are not seperated by "," in this example, so I want to make my code usable in any cases)

example txt file:

```
 16,  11,  10,  16,  24,  40,  51,  61,
 12,  12,  14,  19,  26,  58,  60,  55,
 14,  13,  16,  24,  40,  57,  69,  56,
 14,  17,  22,  29,  51,  87,  80,  62,
 18,  22,  37,  56,  68, 109, 103,  77,
 24,  35,  55,  64,  81, 104, 113,  92,
 49,  64,  78,  87, 103, 121, 120, 101,
 72,  92,  95,  98, 112, 100, 103,  99
```

my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int readMatrix(int *arr, int **mat);
void printMatrix(int **mat, int size);

int main(){
    
    // declare 1D array and allocate memory
    
    int *arr;
    arr = malloc(sizeof(stdin)*sizeof(int));
    
    // declare 2D Matrix and allocate memory
    
    int **mat;
    mat = (int **)malloc(sizeof(stdin)*sizeof(int));
    
    // function implementations
    int size;   
    size = readMatrix(arr, mat);    
    
    printMatrix(mat,size);  
    
    return 0;
}

int readMatrix(int *arr, int **mat){
    
    // reading
    
    int i=0, size=0; // loop var i and size to count the elements of array  
    
    while(scanf("%d,", &arr[i]) != EOF)
    {
        i++;
        size++;
    }
    
    printf("arr[63] = %d \n\n",arr[63]); // VALUE IS CORRECT HERE   
    
    // finding row and column numbers
    int rows = sqrt(size), cols = rows; 

    // appending 1d array into matrix
    int m = 0;
    
    // test printf("rows = %d, cols = %d\n", rows, cols);
    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<cols; j++){
            
            printf("arr[%d] = %d\n",m, arr[m]); // VALUES OF arr[] BECAME WEIRD AFTER arr[12]

            //mat[i][j] = arr[m]; // segmentation fault
            //*(*(mat+i)+j) = arr[m]; // segmentation fault
            //*(*(mat+i)+j) = &arr[m]; // segmentation fault    
            *(mat + i*cols + j) = &arr[m]; // I don't know if this is the proper way but it works
            m++;
        }
    }   
    printf("\narr[63] = %d\n",arr[63]); // HOWWWWW
    
    // return size for further implementations
    //
    return size;
}

void printMatrix(int **mat, int size){
    
    int rows = sqrt(size), cols = rows;

    printf("\nMATRIX A:\n");
        
    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<cols; j++)
        {   
            printf("%d     ", mat[i][j]);
            //if(mat[i][j]>=10 && mat[i][j]<100 ){printf("%d      ", mat[i][j]);}
            //else if(mat[i][j]>=100 ){printf("%d     ", mat[i][j]);}
            //else{printf("%d       ", mat[i][j]);}
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

output:

```
$ ./secondtry < input1.txt
arr[63] = 99

arr[0] = 16
arr[1] = 11
arr[2] = 10
arr[3] = 16
arr[4] = 24
arr[5] = 40
arr[6] = 51
arr[7] = 61
arr[8] = 12
arr[9] = 12
arr[10] = 14
arr[11] = 19
arr[12] = 976
arr[13] = 8
arr[14] = 980
arr[15] = 8
arr[16] = 984
arr[17] = 8
arr[18] = 988
arr[19] = 8
arr[20] = 992
arr[21] = 8
arr[22] = 996
arr[23] = 8
arr[24] = 1000
arr[25] = 8
arr[26] = 1004
arr[27] = 8
arr[28] = 1008
arr[29] = 8
arr[30] = 1012
arr[31] = 8
arr[32] = 1016
arr[33] = 8
arr[34] = 1020
arr[35] = 8
arr[36] = 1024
arr[37] = 8
arr[38] = 1028
arr[39] = 8
arr[40] = 1032
arr[41] = 8
arr[42] = 1036
arr[43] = 8
arr[44] = 1040
arr[45] = 8
arr[46] = 1044
arr[47] = 8
arr[48] = 1048
arr[49] = 8
arr[50] = 1052
arr[51] = 8
arr[52] = 1056
arr[53] = 8
arr[54] = 1060
arr[55] = 8
arr[56] = 1064
arr[57] = 8
arr[58] = 1068
arr[59] = 8
arr[60] = 1072
arr[61] = 8
arr[62] = 1076
arr[63] = 8

arr[63] = 8

MATRIX A:
16     11     10     16     24     40     51     61
11     10     16     24     40     51     61     12
10     16     24     40     51     61     12     12
16     24     40     51     61     12     12     14
24     40     51     61     12     12     14     19
40     51     61     12     12     14     19     976
51     61     12     12     14     19     976     8
61     12     12     14     19     976     8     980
```

Comment: What is your expectation about the value of `sizeof(stdin)`?

Comment: `sizeof(stdin)` is the size of a pointer, and is not related to the amount of data that will be read from the input stream.  It is almost certain that the problem here is that you have not allocated enough space and are overwriting the buffer, causing undefined behavior.  In general, you cannot know how much data will be available until you read it. (If the input is a regular file, you can `stat` it to determine its size, which can allow you to approximate the number of entries, but this is not a good idea.). Read the data and grow the data structures as needed.

Comment: yeah I wasn't sure if it would work, I just started dealing with pointers, arrays, memory allocation in this week. thank you for the explanation. tbh, our professor didn't mention `stat` in the lectures and I have to check it out. so I just tried it with `arr = malloc(16*16*sizeof(int));` and `mat = (int **)malloc(16*16*sizeof(int));`  16*16 because there is one input.txt that has 16x16 matrix in it. the weird numbers disappeared but now I have an repatitive matrix printed out. I guess I also have some problems iterating and appending values into the matrix.

Comment: `int rows = sqrt(size)` Strongly not recommended. If you want to read a matrix of a size that is not known statically, provide the size in the input before the values, and make it the number of rows/columns rather that the total number of elements. Better still, provide 2 sizes for rows and columns separately. Thus `2 2 34 56 78 90` woud specify a 2x2 matrix with elements {34 56 78 90}.

Answer (score 0):

Because we're reading from `stdin`, we can *not* do simple things like:

1. read/parse the first to determine number of columns
2. rewind file
3. read/parse all lines and store in matrix (allocating space as we go)

Note that using `sqrt` on the count to get number of rows/columns is a bit "unique". This is the first time I've seen that done.

When handling a 2D matrix that has dynamic dimensions, it helps to define a control `struct` to be able to store the dimensions. Then, *all* relevant info for the matrix is available to everyone.

In general, I really prefer `fgets/strtok/strtol` over `scanf`.

In this use case, I'm *not* sure if `scanf("%d,",&val)` *can* parse both (e.g.) `103,` and `99`. That is, the last number of the input file has *no* comma after it.

So, I had to refactor the code quite a bit. It is annotated:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifdef DEBUG
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    printf(_fmt)
#else
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    do { } while (0)
#endif

// matrix control
typedef struct {
    int mtx_cols;                       // number of columns
    int mtx_rows;                       // number of rows (input lines)
    int *mtx_base;                      // pointer to matrix data
} mtx_t;

// helper macro to access a given matrix coordinate
#define MTX(_mtx,_irow,_icol) \
    _mtx->mtx_base[((_irow) * _mtx->mtx_cols) + _icol]

// newMatrix -- get new matrix control
mtx_t *
newMatrix(void)
{
    mtx_t *mtx;

    mtx = calloc(1,sizeof(*mtx));

    return mtx;
}

// readMatrix -- read in matrix from stream
void
readMatrix(mtx_t *mtx,FILE *xfin)
{
    char *bp;
    char *cp;
    char buf[1000];

    // get first line as a special case to calculate the number of columns
    fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),xfin);

    // we need to preserve the original data for the second loop below
    char tmp[1000];
    strcpy(tmp,buf);

    // calculate number of columns
    bp = tmp;
    while (1) {
        char *cp = strtok(bp," ,\n");
        bp = NULL;

        if (cp == NULL)
            break;

        mtx->mtx_cols += 1;
    }

    // read in row by row
    while (1) {
        // get current row index and advance the row count
        int irow = mtx->mtx_rows++;

        dbgprt("BUF/%d: %s",irow,buf);

        // add space for this row
        mtx->mtx_base = realloc(mtx->mtx_base,
            sizeof(*mtx->mtx_base) * mtx->mtx_rows * mtx->mtx_cols);
        if (mtx->mtx_base == NULL) {
            perror("realloc");
            exit(2);
        }

        // parse this row
        bp = buf;
        for (int icol = 0;  icol < mtx->mtx_cols;  ++icol) {
            char *cp = strtok(bp," ,\n");
            bp = NULL;

            if (cp == NULL)
                break;

            MTX(mtx,irow,icol) = strtol(cp,&cp,10);
            dbgprt(" %d\n",MTX(mtx,irow,icol));
        }

        // get data for next row
        if (fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),xfin) == NULL)
            break;
    }
}

void
printMatrix(const mtx_t *mtx)
{

    printf("\nMATRIX A:\n");

    for (int irow = 0;  irow < mtx->mtx_rows;  ++irow) {
        for (int icol = 0;  icol < mtx->mtx_cols;  ++icol)
            printf(" %d",MTX(mtx,irow,icol));
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    FILE *xfin;
    if (argc > 0)
        xfin = fopen(*argv,"r");
    else
        xfin = stdin;
    if (xfin == NULL)
        exit(1);

    // declare 1D array and allocate memory
    mtx_t *mtx = newMatrix();

    readMatrix(mtx,xfin);
    printMatrix(mtx);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If `stdin` is a regular file, you can rewind.

Comment: @WilliamPursell yes, of course but as OP described the problem we have to use `stdin` so we can't rely on that. I just used the `fopen` as a debugging aid (for me)